# PHP Fatal error: Interface 'App\\PluginContract' not found

Tags: php, interface

In the same direcory I have:

**html/app**

```
Plugin.php
PluginContract.php
GetUid.php
```

On `GetUid.php` i have this code:

```
<?php

namespace App;

include_once "Plugin.php";
include_once "PluginContract.php";
use Carbon\Carbon;
use TeamSpeak3\Ts3Exception;

class GetUid extends Plugin implements PluginContract
{
    public function isTriggered()
    {

        ...      

    }
}
```

And this is `PluginContract.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

interface PluginContract
{
    public function isTriggered();
}
```

It seems all ok, but I got this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'App\PluginContract' not found in /var/www/html/app/GetUid.php on line 11

The weird thing is that it can load `Plugin.php` without problem but it gets this error for `PluginContract.php` which is in the same folder.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. But it's strange that you're getting double backslashes in the error message. Is there a chance that there's a class auto-loader (maybe Composer's) messing around?

Comment: Yes, there is an autoloader but it cannot be used for that

Comment: Then you should modify it so it doesn't try to load stuff from the `App` namespace because it doesn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was tring to do is add a web interface to a PHP application, I though that I don't need the autoload because it automatically start with the server, but I discovered that adding again the autoload to my index.php I resolved the problem.